# Magento CSS Not Loading

Tags: magento

My magento `CSS` is not loading, and when I try to view source, I noticed something on its src..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\myecommerce-local_comhttp://myecommerce.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/style.css" media="all" />
```

its look like there's a problem in source file.

It should be like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\myecommerce-local_com\skin\frontend\base\default\css\style.css" media="all" />
```

What should I do? to change the source of my style?

Thanks

Comment: How you are giving path in href ?

Comment: the Correct path must be like this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\myecommerce-local_com\skin\frontend\base\default\css\style.css" media="all" />

Comment: i am asking for code you have written to include the css file ?

Comment: of course i Add css in page.xml

<action method="addCss">     <stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet>
</action>

Comment: Actually the href value should be `http://myecommerce.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/style.css` I think you have something in the configuration wrong like base url.

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with my base URL. the value is http:// myecommerce.com/

Comment: Whats the problem with this? Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an Addon like GT Speed do combine/reduce your JS and CSS files? I uninstalled it and the problem was solved.