# Magento CSS Wrong Path

Tags: css, magento

My magento site unable to load the `CSS` because of wrong path. the Path is:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\myecommerce_comhttp://myecommerce.com/skin/frontend/default/theme183v2/css/reset.css" media="all" />`

and the Correct path is

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\myecommerce_com\skin\frontend\default\theme183v2\css\reset.css" media="all" />`

I already change the value of my DB table `core_config_data`, cleared `cache`, etc..

Still not working.

Comment: Duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013561/magento-css-not-loading

Comment: Sorry. Still looking for solution..

Comment: From both questions, you can't see the difference between a file path and a URL.
The file path (the one you use in command line) to your Magento's ROOT FOLDER is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\myecommerce_com` the URL for your Magento is `http://myecommerce.com/`.

Comment: Yes, but when I right click and view source, it came out wrong, it shows the wrong path: 

link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\myecommerce_comhttp://myecommerce.com/skin/frontend/default/theme183v2/css/reset.css" media="all" /

thats why my magento unable to load the css, because the path is incorrect

Comment: Can you take a look at: core_config_data ( base_url and skin_url - entry `web/unsecure/base_skin_url` ), .htaccess file, apache's config...

Comment: web/unsecure/base_url value: http://myecommerce.com/
web/secure/base_url value: http://myecommerce.com/
web/unsecure/base_skin_url value: http://myecommerce.com/

what particular code I'm going to look in .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but mostly for my own documentation:

I've had this problem. There are some things to check:

- Is the folder /media/ writable? This is where Magento stores the combined js and css files.
- Is the folder /var/session and /var/cache writable? Caching needs to be stored somewhere.
- Just to be sure: are the tables core_cache and core_cache_tag truncated?

Making /media/ writable solved the problem for me.

Comment: I forgot to create media folder and set 777 to it

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the control centre

in the System menu, in fact i think this question has been asked before

well

System => Configuration => Web

The main point to watch out for is

i. Url options -> Add store code to Urls should be 'No'

ii. Unsecure -> Base Url should point to your own domain e.g http://mycommerce.com/

iii. Secure -> Base Url should point to your own domain e.g http://mycommerce.com/

also you should have

{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/

for your Base Skin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but found a different solution.

Are you using an Addon like GT Speed to combine or reduce your JS and CSS files?
I uninstalled this plugin and the problem was solved for me. Hope this helps.